# Custom Tumblr OAuthClient with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: .net, oauth, tumblr, dotnetopenauth

Does anyone know any custom OAuthClient for Tumblr? I was going through the [Tumblr api documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) and I ended up having almost no clue on how to create one to use with DotNetOpenAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this may work:

Web Config

```
<add key="TumblrKey" value="x" />
<add key="TumblrSecret" value="x" />
```

Token Store (from/based on the samples project):

```
    public class InMemoryTokenManager : IConsumerTokenManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> tokensAndSecrets = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public InMemoryTokenManager(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerKey");
        }

        ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
    }

    public string ConsumerKey { get; private set; }

    public string ConsumerSecret { get; private set; }

    #region ITokenManager Members

    public string GetTokenSecret(string token)
    {
        return tokensAndSecrets[token];
    }

    public void StoreNewRequestToken(UnauthorizedTokenRequest request, ITokenSecretContainingMessage response)
    {
        tokensAndSecrets[response.Token] = response.TokenSecret;
    }


    public void ExpireRequestTokenAndStoreNewAccessToken(string consumerKey, string requestToken, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret)
    {
        tokensAndSecrets.Remove(requestToken);
        tokensAndSecrets[accessToken] = accessTokenSecret;
    }

    public TokenType GetTokenType(string token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Controller

```
public class TumblrController : Controller
{
    private const string AuthorizationUrl = "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize";
    private const string AccessTokenUrl = "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token";
    private const string RequestTokenUrl = "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token";

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, InMemoryTokenManager> TokenStore = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, InMemoryTokenManager>();

    private static readonly WebConsumer TumblrConsumer;

    static TumblrController()
    {
        TumblrConsumer = new WebConsumer(TumblrServiceProviderDescription, ShortTermUserSessionTokenManager);
    }

    public ActionResult Auth()
    {
        var callBack = new Uri("http://your.com/callback");
        var request = TumblrConsumer.Channel.PrepareResponse(TumblrConsumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callBack, null, null));
        request.Send();

        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    public ActionResult Callback()
    {
        var auth = TumblrConsumer.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        // do something with auth

        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    private static ServiceProviderDescription TumblrServiceProviderDescription
    {
        get
        {
            var tumblrDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription
            {
                UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(AuthorizationUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
                AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(AccessTokenUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
                RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(RequestTokenUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
                TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() }
            };

            return tumblrDescription;   
        }
    }

    private static InMemoryTokenManager ShortTermUserSessionTokenManager
    {
        get
        {
            InMemoryTokenManager tokenManager;
            TokenStore.TryGetValue("Tumblr", out tokenManager);

            if (tokenManager == null)
            {
                tokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TumblrKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TumblrSecret"]);
                TokenStore.TryAdd("Tumblr", tokenManager);
            }

            return tokenManager;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! That did the job!